# React TypeError : cyclic object value nested with plain react app

Tags: reactjs

I've a React 18 / React Router 6 app like this:

HTML:

```
html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/src/assets/vite.svg"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Vite + React + TS</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root" class="h-screen bg-gray-100 w-full"></div>

<script type="module">
    import RefreshRuntime from 'http://localhost:5001/@@react-refresh'
    RefreshRuntime.injectIntoGlobalHook(window)
    window.$RefreshReg$ = () => {}
    window.$RefreshSig$ = () => (type) => type
    window.__vite_plugin_react_preamble_installed__ = true
</script>
<script type="module" src="http://localhost:5001/src/main.tsx"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Main:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.tsx'
import './site.css'
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <HashRouter>
      <App />
    </HashRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

App:

```
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/some-route/*" element={<div>123</div>}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

When calling `/some-route`, I get this error:

```
TypeError: cyclic object value
    parseData https://localhost:7274/#/some-route:8
    i https://localhost:7274/#/some-route:10
    i https://localhost:7274/#/some-route:10
    _ https://localhost:7274/#/some-route:10
    _ https://localhost:7274/#/some-route:10
    l https://localhost:7274/#/some-route:10
    emit https://localhost:7274/#/some-route:439
    emit https://localhost:7274/#/some-route:439
    attachRenderer https://localhost:7274/#/some-route:15681
    initBackend https://localhost:7274/#/some-route:15693
    initBackend https://localhost:7274/#/some-route:15692
    activateBackend https://localhost:7274/#/some-route:736
    setup https://localhost:7274/#/some-route:670
    emit https://localhost:7274/#/some-route:439
    emit https://localhost:7274/#/some-route:439
    setup https://localhost:7274/#/some-route:16180
    <anonymous> https://localhost:7274/#/some-route:16167
    __webpack_require__ https://localhost:7274/#/some-route:20
    <anonymous> https://localhost:7274/#/some-route:84
    <anonymous> https://localhost:7274/#/some-route:87
```

Comment: Can you please share with us other relevant files in your app? Like index.js and other

Comment: Can you share the code for `parseData` function? Unless it is a react-router function.

Comment: Updated the question - `parseData` is a `react-router` function I guess because I didn't implement it.

Comment: Please add a [mre].

Comment: What is your code in your index.html for ? I've never seen this kind of stuff with a vitejs codebase and it looks like it won't work for production. Does the issue still occur if you remove it ?

Answer (score 0):

It's been caused by the React Developer Tools extension for Firefox.

The error is gone when disabling the extension.